# How nodejs can maintain a state of persistent connection

Tags: node.js

I am very new to nodejs and have few doubts regarding it.

With nodejs we can maintain a number of parallel connections. So it means multiple clients can simultaneously maintain connections to nodejs server. There can be authentication required on server side.I am not clear how these authentications and session data can be stored for multiple connections on nodejs server.

Answer (score 3):

Hi Alien and welcome to node.js!

I recommend to use [express](http://expressjs.com/) and [redis](http://redis.io/) to store session information. Take a look at the following [tutorial](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions) for better example.

In addition you can look for redis clients on node.js at the redis site [here](http://redis.io/clients).

Regarding authentication; if you use simple authentication you can implement it by yourself however you can also use existing modules such as [passport](http://passportjs.org/) which is very simple and do the job well.

In general, I'm a veteran Java developer and for the right purposes (mainly web apps) I recommend node.js for its time to market and performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use connect. http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html

```
 connect()
.use(connect.favicon())
.use(connect.cookieParser())
.use(connect.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))
.use(function(req, res, next){
  var sess = req.session;
  // you can set your authentication script through the session here.

}
```

)).listen(3000);